# Canonical Mode With Only 0xFD As EOL?

Tags: serial-port

Should mention Fedora Linux 27.

I almost have canonical mode with only 0xFD as an EOL symbol, but I can't get rid of 0x0A as an EOL symbol as well even though as far as I can tell the entire termios.c_cc[] array is 0 except for c_cc[VEOL] = 0xFD. Should there be a way to have only 0xFD as an EOL symbol?

For background, I want to processes the waterfall scope data from my ham radio (ICOM-7300) and display it on the PC. (Look at YouTube if you're curious what I want to do). The data streams out of the radio pretty fast (60 byte messages every 20 mS at 115,200 baud if I remember correctly). The data is normalized between 0 and 0xA0. There are some control symbols in the protocol. The only place 0xFD shows up is at the end of every single message.

(I understand what raw mode with timed reads is. I wish there were better resolution than 100 mS on the timeout, but I probably could get that to work. I did detect the 0x0A and continue the read which works, although it seems kludgy.)

I have tried

```
memset(ptio->c_cc, 0, sizeof(ptio->c_cc));
ptio->c_cc[VEOL] = 0xFD;
```

and (setting every field of c_cc I could find)

```
...
ptio->c_cc[VSUSP]    = 0;
ptio->c_cc[VEOL]     = 0xFD;
ptio->c_cc[VREPRINT] = 0;
...
ptio->c_cc[VEOL2]    = 0;
```

Just for further illustration here is the error output from my program.

```
serial_listen_thread_loop: short message. Read 37 bytes: 29 33 42 44 1D ... 0A
Bad controller address: 10
serial_listen_thread_loop: short message. Read 41 bytes: FE E0 94 27 00 ... 0A
Bad controller address: 1A
serial_listen_thread_loop: short message. Read 21 bytes: FE E0 94 27 00 ... 0A
Bad controller address: 0A
serial_listen_thread_loop: short message. Read 1 bytes: 0A
Bad controller address: 0F
```

Thank you for any help,
Dan (WV0VW)

Comment: Really, does someone know the answer to this? I have researched a lot (maybe it doesn't show). By my research it seems like I should be able to use canonical mode with exactly one (non-standard) control character, but when I try it it seems like 0x0A (line feed) is always a control character and I can't get rid of it. My next research step would be to read the serial port driver source code (I have glanced through two of those c files). It seems like this should be a normal enough thing that other people would be able to help much quicker than I could read the driver source.

Comment: Even the nerds on the internet won't pay attention to me. sniff.

Answer (score 0):

In case this shows up in somebody's search, it seems that you cannot turn off linefeed as an end of line character, unless you patch the driver code.

I managed to find this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface#Special_characters):

> **Special characters**
>   The c_cc[] array member of the termios data
>   structure specifies all of the (programmatically modifiable) special
>   characters. ... **Non-programmatically modifiable** special characters are
>   **linefeed (ASCII LF)** and carriage return (ASCII CR).[47]

Then later on the same page.

> Line delimiter characters are special characters, and they are end of
>   file, end of line, and **linefeed (ASCII LF)**. The former two are
>   settable programmatically, **whilst the latter is fixed**. ... [49]

The two footnotes [47] and [49] both refer to Zlotnick 1991 which I was not able to research further.